# How to show command 'adb shell input tap x y' feedback on screen?

Tags: adb

I can enable setting "Point Feedback" by the command `ADB shell settings put system show_touches 1`. But When I run `ADB shell input tap x y` or `ADB shell input swipe x1 y1 x2 y2`, there's nothing on the screen.

So, how can I see the touch feedback by the ADB command on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Android > Settings >  Developer Options settings

make sure the `Pointer location` option is enable